# Vue component 'mount' on v-bind change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**`mount` on a component does not fire for `v-bind` changes to the component in the root.**

I have a dynamic component where I often change the value of the data referenced in `v-bind:is` and `v-bind` attributes, switching the current component and its data. This works great to show different "screens" of my application.

I have some logic that happens on `mount` for many of the components. However, this only gets called when the `v-bind:is` value is changed, but no when only the `v-bind` attribute is. That sort of makes sense to me, though I do need to capture either.

I'm new to Vue and there is a lot of documentation. I'm so far unable to determine if there's a built-in functionality for a callback to `v-bind:is` and `v-bind`. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: can you create a testable snippet?

Comment: You might want to look into Watchers. Here is a very explicative answer with some use cases for Watchers and Computed Properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43278470/4576655. Here is the Vue documentation for Watchers and Computed Properties: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers.