# Nothing is displayed when using v-if

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, components, webstorm

I am making a small prototype applicatiom using Vue.js framework and am running into a problem.
I want to always display an input field with a show button, but conditionally display some text. Sounds simple enough but when I try this it just shows a blank page. Here is my component code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="box">
    <input v-model="password" :type = "show === false ? 'text' : 'password'" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="button" @click="show = ! show">Show</button>

    Your password was scored {{ strengthPercentage }}%

        <div v-if="strengthLevel === 1">Your password is very easy to guess. Add some more characters.</div>
        <div v-if="strengthLevel === 2">Your password is not very strong. Add some variations.</div>
        <div v-if="strengthLevel === 3">Your password is quite good. You could still use some more variations though</div>
        <div v-if="strengthLevel === 4">Your password is strong enough. Feel free to use it!</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "PasswordField",

  data: function() {
  return {
    password : '',
    show : false,
  }
  },

  computed: {
      strengthPercentage() {
        let score = 0;
        if(this.password == ""){ return score; }

        for(let i = 0; i<this.password.length; i++){
          if(i<7) {
            score += 5;
          } if(i<9){
            score += 2;
          }
        }

        let variations = {
          digits: /\d/.test(this.password),
          lowercase: /[a-z]/.test(this.password),
          uppercase: /[A-Z]/.test(this.password),
          special: /\W/.test(this.password)
        }

        let variationCount = 0;
        for(let check in variations){
          if(variations[check] === true){ variationCount++; }
        }

        score += (variationCount - 1) * 10;
        if(score>100){ score = 100;}
        return Math.ceil(parseInt(score));
  },

    strengthLevel(){
        let percentage = this.strengthPercentage();
        if(percentage < 30) { return 1; }
        if(percentage < 60) { return 2; }
        if(percentage < 80) { return 3; }
        else { return 4; }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your browser console, you'll see this error message:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.strengthPercentage is not a function"

That points to:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    strengthPercentage() {...},
    strengthLevel() {
      let percentage = this.strengthPercentage(); // Error: 'this.strengthPercentage' is not a function
    }
  }
}
```

While computed props are declared as functions, it resolves to a getter, so you would access it as a simple property:

```js
// BEFORE:
// let percentage = this.strengthPercentage();

// AFTER:
let percentage = this.strengthPercentage;
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-computed-prop-issue-2l7nj?file=/src/components/PasswordField.vue:1809-1857)

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your code
Replace

```
 <input v-model="password" :type = "show === false ? 'text' : 'password'" placeholder="Password">
<button type="button" @click="show = ! show">Show</button>
```

With

```
<input  :type="show==false ? 'password' : 'text'" placeholder="" v-model="password" name="password">
<button type="button" @click="show=!show">Show</button>
```

Example Code Snippet

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      show: false,
      password: '',
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="app">
    <input  :type="show==false ? 'password' : 'text'" placeholder="" v-model="password" name="password">
    <button type="button" @click="show=!show">Show</button>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `show` as computed data, and the text you want display as `data`. So you'll can change that data using methods. You forget to define your function `strengthLevel` inside Methods.

i would recommend you these reads:

- https://michaelnthiessen.com/vue-props-vs-data/
- [VueJs, difference between computed property and watcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277705/vuejs-difference-between-computed-property-and-watcher)

Here an ideia of the code to you: https://gist.github.com/andersonbosa/6651d9e8bb89e2c9a0bccf8a257f7be5